# Is it possible to drag the Dock around the screen?

Tags: dock, windows, ui

As a Windows/Mac/Ubuntu/Fedora user, I have seen many different ways to manage windows. Some of these, like the Windows taskbar and the OS X Dock, are very interesting and highly useful.

One feature that the Windows 7 taskbar has is the ability to drag it around the screen to snap it left, top, right, or down. This is very fun and also practical in many instances.

I've come to like this feature so much that I accidentally did this in Lion - but nothing happened.

Is it possible to drag the Dock around the screen? If so, how?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### Yes!

Hold down <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> while dragging the divider (between applications & documents). The dock will snap to the left, bottom, or right side of the screen as you drag it.

[image]

Comment: +1, good tip. Here's the official Apple Support KB url for the full list of Dock shortcuts: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2307

Comment: Wow! I thought that this would involve some freakishly long AppleScript or other. Thanks!