# How to dock multiple screens in a single screen?

Tags: macos, finder, dock, windows

I am using Macbook Pro and I am trying to dock terminal in the bottom and my webstorm on the top left and safari in top right. I followed the [suggestion](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46143/is-it-possible-to-drag-the-dock-around-the-screen) but I can't get the dividie by holding shift but can't seem to get the divider the solution suggests. How do we get the divider or is this solution is

Comment: The idea of a windows task bar can be re-implemented in software, is this what you seek? If not, are you looking for something that automates resizing windows (or does it really need to change a window and dock it to an arbitrary edge of the screen like a file folder from the days of Classic Mac OS?)

Comment: Please see the question at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/46143/is-it-possible-to-drag-the-dock-around-the-screen I am after the same thing except, I can't seem to find the divider the answer mentioned,

Answer (score 1):

The dock has two sides. One side of the dock is for running and not-running Apps. The other side holds the trash can and all folders, documents and minimized application windows.

I've uploaded some retina sized images with an obscenely large hello arrow to show the dividing line.

When your dock is on the bottom, look for this dark thin line.

[image]

When your dock is on a side, look for a light set of bars.

[image]

Comment: I am really sorry it was my mistake, I did not post the question right. Yes it make sense. But what I am after, if I have three running programs or say three finders I want to have all three finds visible. In windows, I can drag one finder window and pin it to the right side of the screen and it will take 50% of the screen and if I take the second window and pin it to the left then it takes rest of 50% thus I can see both finder windows. I remember seeing demos where Mac users are able to do it. Would like to know how to do this. Sorry again misleading in the previous comment.

Comment: That's not at all how the dock works. You could edit in a drawing of what you want by uploading a picture (even if it's hand drawn). Perhaps someone else knows of add-on software to do what you want.

Comment: Please look at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5mHjJ4xf_K0 8min into the mark.

Comment: You can do this with 3rd-party window-management apps, check out Mac App Store or MacUpdate.

Comment: do you know which app am I looking for?